# Using a decoy breaks my upload on IE. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, upload

I'm using [Valums AJAX Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) and it works just fine, even in IE.

The problem appears when i try to use a decoy to hide Valums markup.

```
$('.control.addphoto:not(.controlactive)').live('click', function(){
    $('#upload input[type=file]').click();
});
```

so, the real input is hidden but clicking my control activates it. The "choosing file" dialog gets displayed just fine in IE but once i click OK the file upload fails (it doesn't even get to the server). When I doesn't use the decoy (i.e. when i click in the input directly) it works just fine.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Why is this happening? I couldn't understand since it's just a decoy and it's calling the actual input. Any clue? Any way to make the decoy more "transparent"?

**obs:** just found out that the decoy isn't working on Opera (doesn't opens the dialog). Again, clicking directly on the input works fine. Shouldn't this be working since i'm using jquery (wich is suposed to be crossbrowser)?

---

### EDIT

- Opera actually doesn't allow triggering the input behavior through a decoy by nature.
- Using Kevin B's alternative i've been able to solve my problem. On the other hand i still don't know why that happened with IE and will keep this question opened for the sake of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this is to make the trigger element invisible, but not hidden, such as giving it the same background color as the element behind it. You can then place it on top of the "decoy" so that it will look like you are clicking on the decoy, while you are actually clicking on the file input.

Comment: why does it work on chrome and firefox then? (your solution is actually interesting by the way)

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't think it was possible for the same reason that triggering the native click event on an anchor tag isn't possible.

Comment: How are you hiding the input? If i hide the input using display: none, the click event will not trigger the opening of the browse dialog in google chrome, but it always opens in IE, both in 8 and 9. I'm building a fiddle to reproduce your situation.

Comment: but besides that, IE still brings the dialog! but somehow it is not "transparent" enough and breaks the upload =/

Comment: yea, that's true. because that i hide it with "visibility: hidden" and "position: absolute"

Comment: So at this point, you can get the dialog to open in every browser, however, in IE the file doesn't actually make it to the server. Just confirming the actual problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4366/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-hugo-leonardo)

Comment: Have you checked the markup you were using for the decoy to ensure that there weren't any extra quotes, Microsoft or "curly" quotes, or any un-closed tags? You know, the obvious but easy to miss stuff.